# How many duplicate numbers repeat in array

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

I want to count how many time duplicate numbers repeat in list.

I have written the code that only find the duplicate numbers in list but my program doesn't count how many time duplicate numbers repeat in array.

I don't want to use any sorting method because I want to understand how it can be implement without any library and sorting methods

```
   #include <stdio.h> 

   int main()
    {
       int list [5] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 4};
 
    int i = 0;  int j = 0;
 
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
       for ( j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
   
        if (list[i] == list[j])
        {
            printf(" Number %d is repeated in list \n", list[i]);
    }
  }
     
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the range of values inside the array limited? Eg min=1, max=4 ... `{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, ...1000000 values ...};` Is the amount of values limited? Eg N<=10... `{-42, 9603814, -7777, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

Comment: As you iterate through array in the outer loop, you need some way to tell if the number at the current index has already been counted. You could do that by allocating an array of flags to mark off the positions that have already been counted, or you could search backwards for the same number because if the same number occurs earlier in the array then this number must have already been counted. The use of a flags array will be faster but uses additional storage, so it's a time/space trade-off.

Comment: What is your expected result for this list? It is unclear whether you want to know how many times each duplicate number is repeated, or the total number of elements which are duplicates.

Comment: Indent your code properly before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to sort your array first (for example via bubble sort. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort ).
After that it's pretty easy to determine the number of duplicate numbers in your list by simply counting the occurence of each number.

The sorting would insure your list transforms from

```
int list [5] = {1, 2, 1, 2, 4};
```

to

```
int list [5] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 4};
```

And the code to count each occurence could then look something like this:

```
int idx, currentNumber, currentCounter, numberOfElements;

currentNumber = list[0];
currentCounter = 0;
numberOfElements = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
for (idx = 0; idx < numberOfElements; idx++) {
   if (list[idx] != currentNumber) {
      printf("List contains number %d %d time(s)\n", currentNumber, currentCounter);

      currentNumber = list[idx];
      currentCounter = 1;
   } else {
      currentCounter++;
   }
}

printf("List contains number %d %d time(s)\n", currentNumber, currentCounter);
```

if you are only interested in duplicates, simply check wheter currentCounter is greater than one. After that, counting the total number of duplicates becomes trivial.